# Sub-d stuck to some edges

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, error

I've got a weird problem, made a circular shape to create a sub-d surface. First drew half the edge ring, mirrored and then extruded the edges to make faces. Making sure to either Merge or Remove double Vertices. The sub-d surface always sticks to two edges, as seen below.

[image: Subd edges stuck]

What's weirder is that when I dissolve a problematic edge, the problem jumps to another edge. These  problem' edges I cannot bevel btw, the bevel only goes one way apparently on them.

[image: After problem edge dissolution]

I know I can fix this by replacing the ring with an inset cylinder face ring for example, but I want to know whats going on. It's important to understand the inner workings of these things imo.

Thanks for any tips and advice.

Comment: Gah! Two minutes after posting I got it fixed. Needed to get all normals in the same direction. Is it better to delete the question or should it stay here answered for information sake?

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question, no problem. It might help someone else, there's no harm in keeping it.